# How to debug inserts with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have come across this, which is a visualliser for LINQ to Entities which can be used in visual studio,

http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-Entity-Visualizer#close=1

The only problem is that it debugs LINQ statements. I am doing an insert statement, is there any way to see what SQL the LINQ to Entities engine is going to execute when doing an insert?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 to Mitch for SQL Profiler.

If not using SQL Server, you can use [this Entity Framework Tracing Provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(SQL.80).aspx) to capture the actual TSQL sent to SQL Server

Comment: Right ... if only I was using SQL server.. Informix unfortunately :( :( :(

Comment: @peter What is an Informix?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the query in the debugger.

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var myQuery = from t in db.Tables
select t;
```

The myQuery will hold your query until it is run. This will work for selects.

Alternatively you could:

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
```

Should log all the calls to your Datacontext

A reference can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah, I am only thinking of debugging inserts, the visualiser I mentioned above works for selects

Comment: @peter. db.Log = Console.Out will work for all statements. Insert Select Delete etc.

Comment: No it won't. That's for LINQ to SQL, not LINQ to Entities.